# Embed YouTube videos in thirdparty player

Tags: web, youtube, media-player

Is there any website video player that I can embed YouTube videos in that also displays a playlist?

I want to be able to see the playlist and as far as I know the YouYube provided player that allows for playlists doesn't show the list unless you click on the playlist button in the top left. I want something with a playlist under or beside the video window that shows at all times.

Answer (score 0):

youtube uses an iframe (as simple as that) to deliver content. Any website can display youtube playlists if the url in the "embed code" has the variables to do that. I forget the url but I am sure it is possible. I hope I got your question right...

Comment: I know I can do it with the iFrame, but the iFrame doesn't support a playlist that is always showing. To see the iFrame playlist you have to click a button in the player window. I want something with a playlist under or beside the video window

Comment: let me check they've just added features...I know that muzu.tv does what you want but all in all in if Google doesn't allow it, I think it's difficult to find a third party website that manages to do that

Comment: I'm not necessarily looking for a youtube alternative. Even a third party player that plays YouTube videos.
OSMPlayer is a good example of what I want, but I can't get it to work. Dev tools tell me there are broken links.

Comment: okay they've added something like that, check out [this test](http://mina-grey.com/playlist.html) I've done for you. Not beautiful, but it's a playlist...If it's more or less what you want I'll update the answer. If not sorry!

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned in the original question, I knew that the YouTube player could do that. But I appreciate the effort :) that's actually how I have implemented the media right now. I'm looking for a better alternative.

Comment: yeah lol. As far as I know that's the only way :) Let's wait for someone else though. One never knows